# Slow torrents on 802.11n, slower internet otherwise

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm having a very strange problem. I have a Linksys E900 with DD-WRT installed on it. I'm running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04. The wireless card in my laptop is Intel Wireless 8260, I have the driver iwlwifi version 4.10.0-33-generic installed.

My ISP gives me 50 Mbps up/down.

Under Wireless settings, if I set Wireless Network Mode to N-only, speeds on my laptop (speedtest.net, fast.com) show 50 Mbps. However speed for torrents is about ~100 KBps.

If I set the Wireless Network Mode to anything else (for example mixed, NG-mixed etc.) I get only 24 Mbps on (speedtest.net, fast.com), but I also get this speed on torrents.

I tested this on the exact same torrent, going back and forth between N-only and other options.

What should I do to get the 50 Mbps speeds on torrents too? Or if that's not possible, is there a way to get 50 Mbps speeds normal and 24 Mbps on torrent (as I already know at least these are possible)?

Edit: I tried the same torrent on my PC (wired connection) and I get 50 Mbps down.

Comment: I’d be curious to know what your bufferbloat grade is in each case. http://speedtest.dslreports.com/

Comment: The website says, "Bufferbloat testing disabled due to high latency" when I do the test.

Comment: Bummer. What part of the world are you connecting from?